# How String s ="sometext" works?

Tags: java, string, oop

In object oriented languages, creation of new object is by using the **new** keyword (since memory allocation in java done dynamically).

Even though String is a class how its object is created without the **new** Keyword?

Even though it uses string pooling I am not able to understand it clearly:
**"It is possible to create a user defined class where we can initialize variable directly like String"**

Comment: No it's not. The compiler treats `String literals` in a special way not possible for other objects (except for autoboxed primitives).

Comment: You cannot, please go through these threads : [Difference between string object and string literal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297867/difference-between-string-object-and-string-literal) [What is the difference between “text” and new String(“text”)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3052442/what-is-the-difference-between-text-and-new-stringtext) for detailed info.

Comment: If you *really* wanted to do something like this, you could switch to Scala (another JVM language), and create an implicit class that automatically turns strings in certain contexts into a class. I'd question why this is a need though.

Comment: @Kayaman (nit-picking) also possible for Lambdas... [:-)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger True, I was going for the "it's not possible", but then I started thinking, and well, thinking has gotten me into trouble before.

Answer (score 5):

The mechanism enabling you to create `String` objects with string literals is built into the compiler and JVM. It is not available for use with objects of user-defined types.

When you write for the first time

```
String s = "sometext";
```

the compiler emits two things:

- A [constant pool](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11700320/335858) entry with `"sometext"` in it, and
- An instruction that sets `s` to reference to the entry in the constant table.

If you write

```
String t = "sometext";
```

in the same class, the compiler will reuse an existing constant for `"sometext"`, rather than creating a new one.

At runtime, JVM creates a new `String` object for each entry from the constant table, and gives your program access to them. Essentially, JVM invokes `new` on your program's behalf, and hands it a ready-to-use object.

Similar system is in play when you create instances of primitive wrappers with autoboxing. The common thing, however, is that it requires support from the compiler, and is not available for user-defined types.

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ This depends on JVM. "Same class" is the required minimum, but [other JVMs](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16690815/335858) can share strings more aggressively.

Answer (score 0):

In Java, Strings are immutable and optionally pooled ("interned").

`"sometext"` is just an instance of a `String` that comes from the static pool.

You cannot create a user-defined String because `java.lang.String` is a `final` class, exactly for the reason of immutability (you can share duplicates by pointing them to a single instance).